# Is Entity Framework useful when the customer can modify the database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, crud

I am trying to evaluate Entity Framework for my ASP.Net MVC based application. 
My company ships a SQL database to our customers and we provide tools for the customer to change this database. They add their own fields, modify existing fields (usually make them larger) but they do not delete any fields we shipped. They can also possibly add their own tables. They modify the database and a metadata table that describes each table/field and our custom validation information for each field. We already have tools to add fields to the database and to populate the meta-information table.
Example,
We ship a table called "Patient". They can add their own field called "LastVisitDate" to this table and then they register this field in our FieldDefinitions table with meta information (e.g. Label = "Last Visit Date", FieldType = "DateTime", MinValue = "1/1/2000",  etc.)
Given this scenario, we will generate a UI on the fly based on an xml file (e.g: (simplified)

```
<fields>
    <Patient.LastName>
    <Patient.FirstName>
    <Patient.LastVisitDate> <!-- Added by customer -->
<fields>
```

Basically, every time our application is fired up, I can never be sure what the table structure is (there are hundreds of such tables but I'm leaving them out for clarity).

Can entity framework be used in such a scenario? I'd appreciate any direction on this. I am reluctant to have to construct sql queries on the fly to achieve CRUD operations but it is not clear to me how to achieve this using EF.

Thanks

Comment: It depends on how much work you're willing to put into it. Entity Framework is only useful here if you can add properties describing the fields. That requires dynamically creating the type definitions and registering them using a new `DbModelBuilder`. Are you familiar with `TypeBuilder`? The dynamically created type can inherit from a base `Patient` class, so that you can have strongly typed queries (`from patient in context.Patients where patient.LastName == "Doe" select patient`) that also pull in the user-created fields.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think EF will be good for you based on your requirement. The biggest advantage of EF which save developer time is that it allow you write strong typed LINQ query and use EF framework to translate them to SQL Query.

In your case, I don't think there is a easy way to do this. So no benefits to use EF in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The greatest problem is that an EF context either generates types (model first) or works against types that you specify (code first). Maybe that in itself would not be a problem if *somehow* you would succeed in dynamically generating an ObjectContext/DbContext. The problem is that that would break the rest of your code base.

It is not uncommon to see [EAV models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) in medical environments, or any environment where attributes of entities need to be changed continually by the users themselves. I don't know if you ever considered that as an alternative? Mind you, it is not a clean and easy solution, but I would contend that it is better (or less bad) than your current solution, because at least it does not require continuous schema changes.

If there are immutable parts in the schema (I hope there are plenty), you could start using EF for those of course.

Comment: Thanks GertArnold. EAV is a good thought but unfortunately it is impossible to switch without a company-wide effort and without breaking every application we have. The reason I am considering EF for my scenario is the ease of binding once a proper model is defined (on the fly) in my case.

Comment: Also, GertArnold, why do you think that generating the DBContext would  break the rest of my code?

Comment: Because the rest of your code will be built on top of the types in the context. Not all of it, of course, but some parts will not compile any more when a context is changed.